# Component not updating on Map (dictionary) state change using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I have a child component that is supposed to display names based on a visibility filter with checkboxes. I use a dictionary to keep track of the checked state for each name. However, when I update the dictionary the child does not update.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8k39xmxl52

These are the components:

```
const App = () => {
  const [names, setNames] = useState(seedNames);
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(new Map());

  const handleHidden = e => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const hidden = e.target.checked;

    setHidden(hidden.set(name, hidden));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VisibilityFilter
        names={names}
        hidden={hidden}
        handleHidden={handleHidden}
      />
      <DisplayNames names={names} hidden={hidden} />
    </div>
  );
};

const VisibilityFilter = ({ names, hidden, handleHidden }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map(name => (
        <div key={name}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={name}
            checked={hidden.get(name)}
            onChange={handleHidden}
            defaultChecked
          />
          <span>{name}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


const DisplayNames = ({ names, hidden }) => {
  const visibleNames = names.filter(name => !hidden.get(name));

  return (
    <div>
      {visibleNames.map(name => (
        <div key={name}>{name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of immutable state is idiomatic to React, it's expected that simple types like plain objects and arrays are used.

Map `set` returns the same map, while `useState` supports only immutable states. In case setter function is called with the same state, a component is not updated:

```
setHidden(hidden.set(name, hidden))
```

The state should be kept immutable:

```
setHidden(new Map(hidden.set(name, hidden)))
```

This may introduce some overhead and defy possible benefits of ES6 `Map`. Unless `Map` features like strict item order and non-string keys are in demand, it's preferable to use plain object for the same purpose.

Comment: I wrote a more detailed explanation to Estus' answer - https://medium.com/swlh/using-es6-map-with-react-state-hooks-800b91eedd5f

Comment: Nice write-up. Notice that `<li key={k}>` doesn't take non-string keys into account, which is an important and probably main reason to use maps instead of objects.